# Кусочно-линейная функция

Tags: python

[image: нужно построить график кусочно-линейной функции]

можете подсказать в чем может быть проблема,что идет неправильно вывод графика кусочно-линейной функции?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x=float(input("enter x="))
def func(x):
  if -10<=x<-5:
    return -8*x-7
  elif -5<=x<-3:
    return -6*x+3
  elif -3<=x<-2:
    return -5*x+6
  elif -2<=x<2:
    return -2*x+11
  elif 2<=x<8:
    return 0.5*x+6
  elif 8<=x<=15:
    return 5*x+30
x=np.linspace(-10,15,200)
y = np.vectorize(func, otypes=[float])#возвращает ссылку на "векторизированную" функцию. 
graph1 = plt.plot(x, y(x))
```

[image]

а вот что он должен выводить какой график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит «неправильно»?

Comment: график функции не так отображается как должен отображаться

Comment: Как он отображается и как он должен отображаться?

Comment: я добавил в правке рисунок как он у меня отображается

Comment: И что конкретно вас на нём смущает?

Comment: в том, то что он выглядеть немного по-другому, чем должен выглядеть на самом деле

Comment: я добавил в правке рисунок, какой должен получиться график

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Когда ваша проблема заключается в том, что функция прерывна, но график непрерывный, вы можете нарисовать две частичные функции в тот же самую систему координат (объект типа `axes`)

Замените последние 3 строки вашей программы на

```
y = np.vectorize(func)             # возвращает ссылку на "векторизированную" функцию. 

__, ax = plt.subplots()            # __ вместо fig, т.к. это имя дальше не используется

x = np.linspace(-10, 7.999, 200)   # Первый интервал
ax.plot(x, y(x), color="b")

x = np.linspace(8, 15, 200)        # Второй интервал
ax.plot(x, y(x), color="b")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В точке -2 есть ещё один разрыв

Comment: @andreymal, да, спасиво. Я попытался также разделить мой первый интервал в этой точке (получая 3 интервалa), но разрыв такой маленький, что график остался практически тем же.